# How to pass object from superclass constructor in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, object, constructor, superclass

I created my Frames and I want to extend the panel from superclass with some new buttons. How can I pass the panel object from the superclass? This is first frame:

```
public class FirstFrame extends JFrame {
    public FirstFrame(String title) throws HeadlessException {
        super(title);
        ....
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        ....
    }
}
```

And the second frame, where I want to add additional button:

```
public class SecondFrame extends FirstFrame {
    public SecondFrame(String title) throws HeadlessException {
        super(title);
        JButton btnMove = new JButton("Przenies zajecia");
        JButton btnDispMode = new JButton("Tryb wyświetlania");
        btnPanel.add(btnMove); // doesn't work
    }
}
```

Comment: Have `btnPanel` as a field of `FirstFrame` not as a local variable

Comment: Personally, I think extending JFrame is a bad design.  I never see new behavior added.  It makes more sense to me to extend JPanel and inject that into the JFrame via constructor.

Comment: @ScaryWombat thank you, it was very simple though...

Comment: @duffymo I read it on stack some time ago, somebody recommended this kind of design because having more JFrame than one is worse

Comment: I don't know what that means.  I disagree - I think it's a bad idea.  Your call.

Comment: @duffymo they called it  "Singleton" design pattern

Comment: That's even worse - Singleton is one of the most reviled patterns in the GoF book.  Stop following shallow recommendations and think more for yourself.

Comment: @duffymo I just tought it would be ok and in my opinion it works just fine. Can you explain why it is so bad? How can I manage windows in Gui then?

Comment: Please do some research.  SO comments aren't suitable for such a thing.